# How can I invoke from C a function created in MATLAB and compiled in C?

Tags: c++, c, matlab, matlab-compiler

My problem: 
I have to perform complex calculations from a C program, but it seems impossible. So I want to use MATLAB from C. I have found that can be compiled MATLAB functions to C with the MATLAB command:

```
mcc-B cpplib: getTeta getTeta.m
```

And getTeta.m is:

```
function teta = getTeta(P,phi,tetaviejo,y)
    landa=0.98;
    Kn=P*phi*inv(landa+phi'*P*phi);
    teta=tetaviejo+Kn*(y'-phi'*tetaviejo);
return
```

Once here do not know how to call the function created in C. Any idea?

Comment: _Once here do not know how to call the function created in C._  Firstly, what you have posted is not a C function.  Here is a ***[step by step instruction set](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2011/11/14/generating-c-code-from-your-matlab-algorithms/#2)*** that will walk you through a very simple Matlab to C conversion, using Matlab native tools. (codegen)

Comment: One option you have is to call the Matlab engine directly from C.  You could start reading about this at http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_external/using-matlab-engine.html

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use [ceval](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/coder.ceval.html) from MATLAB coder package.